# Finding the sum of column data of each row in each day hour in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I am very much new to PostgreSQL. Recently I am working on a database where there is a table name "store". store has item_id as primary key. here is a demo data in my store table :

| id | item_id | supplier_id | received | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 6 | 2019-3-21 11:55:23 | 54 |
| 99 | 42 | 4 | 2019-3-21 11:23:12 | 98 |
| 19 | 39 | 6 | 2019-3-21 12:59:23 | 21 |
| 69 | 82 | 3 | 2019-3-21 10:29:11 | 32 |

**I want to formulate a query that will return the number of supplies(supplies = sum of quantity) received in each day hour.the output will include the day hour sort by hour.**

The output will be like this :

| hour | supplies |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-3-21 11:00:00 - 11:59:59 | 152 |
| 2019-3-21 12:00:00 - 12:59:59 | 21 |

Can anyone help me out to formulate this query in postgreSQL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a calendar table approach here.  Assuming we only need to cover a 24 hour period on the single date `2019-03-21`, we can try:

```sql
with dates as (
    select generate_series(
       (date '2019-03-21')::timestamp,
       (date '2019-03-22')::timestamp,
       interval '1 hour'
     ) as dt
)

select
    d.dt::date::text || ' ' ||
        to_char(d.dt::time,'HH24:MM:SS') || ' - ' ||
        to_char(d.dt::time + interval '1 hour' - interval '1 second', 'HH24:MM:SS') as hour,
    coalesce(sum(s.quantity), 0) as supplies
from dates d
left join store s
    on s.received >= d.dt and s.received < d.dt + interval '1 hour'
group by
    d.dt
order by
    d.dt;
```

### Demo

Note: If you only want to view hours which had a non zero sum of quantity, simply add the following `having` clause to the above query:

```sql
having sum(s.quantity) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you. but what if there are multiple dates instead of single day?  and I want each day each hour.

Comment: @RayhanAhmedRakib Then just edit the call to `generate_series` to start on the earliest date, and end on the latest date which you want to be reported.

Comment: Your solution only work till 12:00 but ignores the supplies from 13:00,14:00,15:00 etc.

Comment: I disagree.  My solution completely works for the sample data you showed.  If you have other data, then maybe there is some edge case which I could not see.

Comment: in my dataset there are some supplies which are received after 13:00 and this query unfortunately skipping them :(

Comment: @RayhanAhmedRakib Not sure if it matters, but I edited my answer to display the hours in 24 hour time.  I think my answer _was_ capturing the sums, but would have bucketed `14:00` under `02:00` PM.